# How can I use python to merge dataframes or CSV files base on a key value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two csv files, first one (master file) contain Keys and its values and the second one (daily file) contain key and some other columns.

Example file (master file)

```
  Key  value
   A     1
   B     2
   c     3
```

Example file (daily file)

```
 Name  Key  date
 Red   A    dd/mm/yy
 Blue  B    dd/mm/yy
 Pink  C    dd/mm/yy
```

The outcome file I need looks like this:

```
 Name   Key   value   date
 Pink    C      3     dd/mm/yy
 Blue    B      2     dd/mm/yy
 Red     A      1     dd/mm/yy
```

I've tried using dataframe and creating dicts from external file or dataframe but not idea how can I do the lookup base on key and obtain its value.

Comment: What is the logic that would take inputs of `C, 3` and `Pink, C, dd/mm/yy` and merge them to become `Red, C, 3, dd/mm/yy`?

Comment: Sorry my mistake C is always Pink as A is always Red, I just wanted to illustrate that it doesn't need to follow the same order.

Comment: I have modified the question base on the valid answer since I found merge approach easier to implement for my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your csv files as you've described, you can do this very easily with Pandas to merge records from both files with matching `Key` values:

```py
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('master.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('daily.csv')
df3 = df2.merge(df1, left_on='Key', right_on='Key')
```

This gives you a merged dataframe for all data with matching `Key`s:

```
   Name Key      date  value
0   Red   A  dd/mm/yy      1
1  Blue   B  dd/mm/yy      2
2  Pink   C  dd/mm/yy      3
```

If you want the columns in the order in your question you can just add

```
df3 = df3[['Name', 'Key', 'value', 'date']]
```

Comment: Great!! merge option was a good approach, Ive had to do some changes because int64 in my data files  but works fine, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code, may be it will help you and you will get your desire output

```
# import Library
import pandas as pd 

# Create Dataframe as like as imported CSV file for your (master file) and (daily file)
masterfile = {'key':['A','B','C'], 'value':[1,2,3]}
dailyfile = {'Name':['Red','Blue','Pink'],'key':['A','B','C'], 'date':['dd/mm/yy','dd/mm/yy','dd/mm/yy']}

masterfil = pd.DataFrame(data=masterfile, index=None)
dailyfile = pd.DataFrame(data=dailyfile, index=None)

# Change the order of dataframe(descending order)
df_masterfil = masterfil.sort_values(by='key', ascending=False)
df_dailyfile = dailyfile.sort_values(by='key', ascending=False)

# merge the both dataframe or csv file
df=df_dailyfile.merge(df_masterfil)
df=df[['key', 'value', 'date']]

dailyfile['Name']

# As like your dataset
result= pd.concat([dailyfile['Name'], df1], axis=1)
result
```

[image]

Comment: It works as well, the problem is that my files are not exactly as it described in the question (my mistake, just I wanted to put more clear examples). concat options has given many problem with different format files. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

i think the most basic answer to your question is given by [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp).

How you first put the content of your files into dicts is a different story that starts by [reading the file](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_open.asp). 
I think i would choose the `readline()` option and `split()`ting the gotten strings into key and value pairs for the `dict()`

Comment: I think your answer match better even to my question, but probably I was wrong formulating the question. Merge option save me time and code but I found well your advise as well. Thanks!